# Phrase for "a person who cares much more about other people's business than their own"

Tags: phrase-request

In the Persian/Farsi language there exists a phrase **"a bowl which is hotter than the soup"**, which means:

> A person who cares ridiculously about others' business more than
>   his/her own business.

I only know the above expression, a translation from Persian to English which is equal to this but it doesn't work because I want an English expression, term or adjective to express this character.

Could you please help me to create it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't think of an idiom, but, insofar as words go, you could try *[meddler](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/meddler)* or [*busybody*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/busybody).

If those are close, you could also start there and venture forth with a thesarus.

Answer (score 1):

If a single word will suffice, those suggested by J.R. will do very well.

But if you want a longer, proverbial expression, you may pick any verse from Matthew 7:3-5:

> 1 Judge not, that ye be not judged.
>   2 For with what judgment ye judge, ye shall be judged: and with what measure ye mete, it shall be measured to you again.
>   3 And why beholdest thou the mote that is in thy brother's eye, but considerest not the beam that is in thine own eye?
>   4 Or how wilt thou say to thy brother, Let me pull out the mote out of thine eye; and, behold, a beam is in thine own eye?
>   5 Thou hypocrite, first cast out the beam out of thine own eye; and then shalt thou see clearly to cast out the mote out of thy brother's eye.

Comment: It is nice but I need another dictionary to translate them to the standard English! :))

Comment: @PersianCat That **is** standard English. ;} If you need the vulgate, try the [New International Version](http://niv.scripturetext.com/matthew/7.htm)

Comment: It is blocked in Iran. :((

Comment: @PersianCat Oh, dear. "1 “Do not judge, or you too will be judged. 2 For in the same way you judge others, you will be judged, and with the measure you use, it will be measured to you. 3 Why do you look at the speck of sawdust in your brother’s eye and pay no attention to the plank in your own eye? 4 How can you say to your brother, ‘Let me take the speck out of your eye,’ when all the time there is a plank in your own eye? 5 You hypocrite, first take the plank out of your own eye, and then you will see clearly to remove the speck from your brother’s eye."

Comment: Thanks for the translation! :)) Emm but these are very general moral advices not a phrase or expression which describes a character.

Comment: @PersianCat In Christian or previously Christian countries (much of the Americas and Europe), I suspect references to specks (very small/minor object; dust) and/or planks (very large/obvious object; piece of wood) in eyes will often be understood as references to these passages and the point understood. It’s not *quite* as perfect a match (more about general hypocrisy), but another passage in the Bible about “physician, heal thyself!” (i.e. worry about your own problems) is even more famous and well-known. That said, using religious references may imply things you don’t mean to.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t a phrase to describe them, but I heard this expression growing up: “mind your own beeswax!” I suspect it originated as a funny variant on “mind your own business,” meaning “don’t be so concerned with the business of others.”

More words for busybody, not used as often modernly but people will generally know what you mean:
“buttinsky” (they “butt in” to other’s business),
“nosy Parker” (not sure of the origin of this, though “nosy” by itself is also an adjective for a person who is curious and inquisitive into things others would prefer keep private),
“snoop” (this is a noun or a verb, a prying person and the action of prying into private things),
yenta (this is from Yiddish but is used in English sometimes; originally a yenta was a matchmaker, a marriage-arranger, but it came to mean someone who was always involved in the affairs of others);
All these courtesy of https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/busybody
“he has his nose in everyone’s business.”

“Kibitzer” - a person who doesn’t have a hand of cards to play themselves, but looks over the shoulders of players’s to see their hands and tells them how they ought to play (especially if they look at more than one hand and base their advice on that knowledge). This is sometimes used out of the playing card context for someone who always tells other people how they should do a task or live their life. Kibitz can also be a verb, and the participle kibitzing.

Here is an idiomatic phrase: “back-seat driver.” Similar to kibitzer, it came from literally someone sitting in the back seat of a car who constantly second-guesses the driver’s decisions, tells them they should be doing something else, etc, but quickly became a metaphor for telling others how to run their life.